# How can I remove the greasiness from my ice cream?

Tags: food-science

I am using 35% whole cream and 3.25% whole milk to make my home made ice cream and it leaves a greasy aftertaste. How can I improve this?

- glucose de 46,
- skim milk powder
- modified cornstarch
- sugar
- cream cheese
- 35% cream
- 3.25 milk

Comment: We'd need to see your whole recipe to answer beyond the rather obvious "use *less cream* or use *light cream* or *half and half* rather than *heavy cream.*" Or use a lower percentage if you buy via percentage rather than descriptions (regional variance.) Please find the edit button and include the recipe and procedure. We don't want questions seeking a recipe *as an answer*, but we do fairly well on figuring out where a recipe or procedure looks wrong, if we have the recipe or procedure in the question. Pre-chilling in the refrigerator before churning can also help.

Comment: i am using glucose de 46, skim milk powder modified cornstarch, sugar,cream cheese 35% cream and 3.25 milk

Comment: Not a list of ingredients - the recipe, including **amounts** and **procedures.** Please edit the question with that information. Cream cheese is also going to tend towards your "*greasy after taste.*"

Comment: I have put the ingredients you listed into the question, please edit to add amounts of each and your procedure.

Comment: From the punctuation in your ingredient clarification post, I'm unclear on what is meant by "cream cheese 35% cream": are you talking about the us commercial food product called "cream cheese" e.g. Philadelphia brand, etc.?  As Ecnerwal says, it sounds like a possible source of "greasy aftertaste".  For comparison purposes, have you tried any recipes that don't include this ingredient?

Comment: If this is a recipe that others have used successfully, consider that you may have *over-churned.* Excessive churning is almost changing milk/cream to butter.

Comment: It sounds as if you over-churned it. That turns the cream into more of a butter consistency. Try less beating and more folding.

Answer (score 2):

I'd find a recipe without cream cheese.

You can make ice cream with all the other ingredients without it being greasy, assuming "glucose de 46" is just glucose. Cream cheese can be greasy, though, so it's almost certainly the culprit. (I suppose you should also check that you're using the right kind, i.e. not using full-fat when the recipe calls for low-fat.)

There's not really a lot of point trying to modify the existing recipe to remove it; you'd have to look at other recipes to get the right ratios anyway, so you might as well just make one of those other recipes.